# Delete documents of type in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, documents

I want to delete all the documents indexed within a type in Elasticsearch, using the HTTP/REST api, but I don't want to delete the mapping for this type

How can I build the query in the URL to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before executing command, index/mapping state; (screenshots taken from *elasticsearch head plugin* web interface)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Command;

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/publishercategoryeu/autocomplete/_query' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
'
```

Result;

[image]

After executing command, index/mapping state;

[image]

[image]

[image]

As we can see we deleted all the documents indexed within a type(mapping) without delete index or type(mapping).

Comment: 'twitter' is index name and 'tweet' is mapping name in the command. Did you replace them correctly with your case?

Comment: sure. I think it depends on elasticsearch version. I also have some queries from elasticsearch guide and get an unparsable exception.

Comment: I will check/test my post and inform you tonight. Please be patient. :)

Comment: I tested and detailed my post. As you said elasticsearch version is important for this action. At documentation (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) there is a note mentioning this.

Comment: note: delete by query is deprecated since 1.5.3 and no longer works in 2.0

Answer (score 8):

A simple delete by query with a match_all query should do the trick. 
You can grab more info here :

[delete by query api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/delete-by-query/)

Alternatively, you can delete the whole type and make use of the template api. Just drop a file in your config/templates/ folder containing your template, and you'll never loose it. The mapping will indeed be lost when you'll delete the mapping, but the template will be reused as soon as you index something again. Here's some more info :

[template api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-templates/)

EDIT: new delete api: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html

Comment: Seems that's deprecated

Answer (score 4):

With the following command in the elasticsearch head plugin I was able to delete all documents of type `logs` from the `logstash` index without deleting the mapping:

```
{"query":{"match_all":{}}}
```

[image: Deleting documents with Elasticsearch head plugin]

To free space on the disk you must also optimize the index (Actions->Optimize for index `logstash` in the head plugin) after deleting the documents.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers will not work with the most recent version of `Elasticsearch`. "Delete by query" was deprecated from `Elasticsearch 2.0`.  `Elasticsearch` documentation says that it can cause an OutOfMemoryError during concurrent indexing and can cause primary and replica to become inconsistent.  If you want follow the history of the issue in [Github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7052).

It now takes multiple steps in order to delete all documents from a `type`.

1. Find all the ids of the document that you need to delete.  The most efficient way to perform this operation is to use the [scroll/scan API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-scroll.html) to find all the matching ids for a given type.
2. Issue a bulk request to delete the documents by ids.  An example provided below.

   ```
   curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_bulk' -d '
       { "delete": { "_index": "index", "_type": "type", "_id": "1"}
       { "delete": { "_index": "index", "_type": "type", "_id": "2"}'
   ```

Note that if you are providing a text file input to curl, you **must** use the `--data-binary` flag instead of plain `-d`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in golang, using the "[olviere/elastic](https://github.com/olivere/elastic)" library, you can use this code, assuming you have a client `yourClient`, and `yourIndex` and `yourType`:

```
    bq := elastic.NewBoolQuery()
    bq.Must(elastic.NewMatchAllQuery())
    _, err := elastic.NewDeleteByQueryService(yourClient).
        Index(yourIndex).
        Type(yourType).
        Query(bq).
        Do()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_query?q=user:kimchy'

$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_query' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

use:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://{server}/{index_name}/{type_name}/'
```

(as in [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html))

Comment: Although this appears to work, it is not part of the documentation for delete_by_query. However that also deletes the mapping, so you should use the full delete_by_query, with a match-all query.

Comment: This deletes the whole document type and not only the documents.