# How to really delete document of a certain type in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to delete all of my document of _type=varnish-request on my elasticsearch.
I installed the delete by query plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html)

I did DELETE http://localhost:9200/logstash*/_query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [        
        { "match": {"_type":"varnish-request"}},
        { "match": {"_index":"logstash-2016.02.05"}}     
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And it's OK

```
{"took":2265842,"timed_out":false,"_indices":{"_all":{"found":3062614,"deleted":3062614,"missing":0,"failed":0},"logstash-2016.02.05":
{"found":3062614,"deleted":3062614,"missing":0,"failed":0}},"failures":[]}
```

curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort
Before the clean

- yellow open logstash-2016.02.05 5 1 4618245 0   4.1gb   4.1gb

After the clean

- yellow open logstash-2016.02.05 5 1 1555631 3062605 4.1gb 4.1gb

The whole point is to 'light' my ES server by removing useless data. But here I see that the index size is still the same.

I already check [Delete documents of type in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013895/delete-documents-of-type-in-elasticsearch) but no luck

I try with [elasticsearch: how to free store size after deleting documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608417/elasticsearch-how-to-free-store-size-after-deleting-documents)

POST http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016.02.05/_forcemerge

```
{"_shards":{"total":10,"successful":5,"failed":0}}
```

But still

- yellow open logstash-2016.02.05 5 1 1555631 3062605 4.1gb 4.1gb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is correct. Now you simply need to call [`_optimize`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-optimize.html) (or [`_forcemerge`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html) if you're using ES 2.1+) by enabling `only_expunge_deletes`. This will delete the segments with deleted documents and free some space.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_optimize?only_expunge_deletes=true'
```

or

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_forcemerge?only_expunge_deletes=true'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Val, it works ```yellow open logstash-2016.02.05 5 1 1555631 0 1.3gb 1.3gb```